# Can I append an array to 'formdata' in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multipartform-data

I'm using FormData to upload files. I also want to send an array of other data.

When I send just the image, it works fine. When I append some text to the formdata, it works fine. When I try to attach the 'tags' array below, everything else works fine but no array is sent.

Any known issues with FormData and appending arrays?

Instantiate formData:

`formdata = new FormData();`

The array I create. Console.log shows everything working fine.

```
        // Get the tags
        tags = new Array();
        $('.tag-form').each(function(i){
            article = $(this).find('input[name="article"]').val();
            gender = $(this).find('input[name="gender"]').val();
            brand = $(this).find('input[name="brand"]').val();
            this_tag = new Array();
            this_tag.article = article;
            this_tag.gender = gender;
            this_tag.brand = brand;
            tags.push(this_tag);    
            console.log('This is tags array: ');
            console.log(tags);
        });
        formdata.append('tags', tags);
        console.log('This is formdata: ');
        console.log(formdata);
```

How I send it:

```
        // Send to server
        $.ajax({
            url: "../../build/ajaxes/upload-photo.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $.fancybox.close();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why are you adding properties to an array? Use an object instead.

Comment: I suspect a PHP background. Arrays don't really work like this in Javascript.

Comment: That's exactly it :) I will use an object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [appending array to FormData and send via AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104078/appending-array-to-formdata-and-send-via-ajax)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

How about this?

```
formdata.append('tags', JSON.stringify(tags));
```

... and, correspondingly, using `json_decode` on server to deparse it. See, the second value of FormData.append can be...

> a Blob, File, or a string, if neither, the value is converted to a
>   string

The way I see it, your `tags` array contains objects (@Musa is right, btw; making `this_tag` an Array, then assigning string properties to it makes no sense; use plain object instead), so native conversion (with `toString()`) won't be enough. JSON'ing should get the info through, though.

As a sidenote, I'd rewrite the property assigning block just into this:

```
tags.push({article: article, gender: gender, brand: brand});
```

Comment: The only problem is JSON.stringify() gives me the output with escaped quotes. That makes it unable to be interpreted on the PHP side. Do you know how to destringify?

Comment: Here is the output [{\"article\":\"Article\",\"gender\":\"Gender\",\"brand\":\"Brand\"}]

Comment: If you are using asp.net with automatic mapping or something similar, then this answer is what you need.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28434829/625581

Comment: hi @raina77ow i want to like this send array but server side i am not getting this array object image is getting but array not getting?can you please help me

Comment: Shouldn't have to do this. The easy way is append to a key with square brackets.

Comment: if i gave json stringfy means i cant insert that tag table. i use form data in post man

Answer (score 41):

Writing as

```
var formData = new FormData;
var array = ['1', '2'];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    formData.append('array_php_side[]', array[i]);
}
```

you can receive just as normal array post/get by php.

Comment: How to collect this data on server side

Comment: @RahulMatte Server side sent via GET: `print_r($_GET['array_php_side']);` result: `Array([0] => 1, [1] => 2)`

Answer (score 22):

We can simply do like this.

```js
formData = new FormData;
words = ["apple", "ball", "cat"]
words.forEach((item) => formData.append("words[]", item))

// verify the data
console.log(formData.getAll("words[]"))
//["apple", "ball", "cat"]
```

On server-side you will get `words = ["apple", "ball", "cat"]`

Comment: This didn't work for me. 

I got
```words[] : (binary)
 words[] : (binary)```

Comment: Strange that all over the internet, there are so small infos about this. In my case for PHP backend it does work very well surprisingly.

Answer (score 18):

use `"xxx[]"` as name of the field in formdata (you will get an array of - stringified objects - in you case)

so within your loop

```
$('.tag-form').each(function(i){
            article = $(this).find('input[name="article"]').val();
            gender = $(this).find('input[name="gender"]').val();
            brand = $(this).find('input[name="brand"]').val();
            this_tag = new Array();
            this_tag.article = article;
            this_tag.gender = gender;
            this_tag.brand = brand;
            //tags.push(this_tag);    
            formdata.append('tags[]', this_tag);
...
```

Comment: Brilliant! My needs are similar to the OP's, but I want to fill the `FormData` object with an array of file inputs. I am attempting to upload an arbitrary number of files, with AJAX, which the user specifies with standard form input elements. The server-side implementation requires all of the files to be nested under a single key, and this was the only way I was able to achieve that. There is absolutely no mention of this array-notation technique at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append . I can't thank you enough, halfbit!

Comment: I added an example to the above-cited documentation that demonstrates this specific usage. The ability to include the square brackets is hugely useful when dealing with multi-file uploads because the resultant data structure is so much more conducive to looping. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

Function:

```
function appendArray(form_data, values, name){
    if(!values && name)
        form_data.append(name, '');
    else{
        if(typeof values == 'object'){
            for(key in values){
                if(typeof values[key] == 'object')
                    appendArray(form_data, values[key], name + '[' + key + ']');
                else
                    form_data.append(name + '[' + key + ']', values[key]);
            }
        }else
            form_data.append(name, values);
    }

    return form_data;
}
```

Use:

```
var form = document.createElement('form');// or document.getElementById('my_form_id');
var formdata = new FormData(form);

appendArray(formdata, {
    sefgusyg: {
        sujyfgsujyfsg: 'srkisgfisfsgsrg',
    },
    test1: 5,
    test2: 6,
    test3: 8,
    test4: 3,
    test5: [
        'sejyfgjy',
        'isdyfgusygf',
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the way I did it:

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('id', class.id);
data.append('name', class.name);

class.people.forEach((person, index) => {
    data.append(`people[${index}].id`, person.id);
    data.append(`people[${index}].firstname`, person.firstname);
    data.append(`people[${index}].lastname`, person.lastname);

    // Append images
    person.images.forEach((image, imageIndex) =>
        data.append(`people[${index}].images`, {
            name: 'image' + imageIndex,
            type: 'image/jpeg',
            uri: image,
        })
    );
});
```

*I am using React on the frontend and Asp.Net on the backend.*

Answer (score 4):

Simply you can do like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('array[key1]', this.array.key1);
formData.append('array[key2]', this.array.key2);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var formData = new FormData; var arr = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

arr.forEach(item => {
    formData.append(
        "myFile",item
    ); });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var formData = new FormData;
var alphaArray = ['A', 'B', 'C','D','E'];
for (var i = 0; i < alphaArray.length; i++) {
    formData.append('listOfAlphabet', alphaArray [i]);
}
```

And In your request you will get array of alphabets.

Comment: Brillant idea, but this works in my code only if brackets `[]` are used: `formData.append('listOfAlphabet[]', alphaArray [i]);`. Otherwise PHP does not get the full array, but only the last item.

Answer (score 1):

You can only stringify the array and append it. Sends the array as an actual Array even if it has only one item.

```
const array = [ 1, 2 ];
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("numbers", JSON.stringify(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me when I sent file + text + array:

```
const uploadData = new FormData();
if (isArray(value)) {
  const k = `${key}[]`;
  uploadData.append(k, value);
} else {
  uploadData.append(key, value);
}


const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sending files(array) using formData in vuejs 
for me below code is working

```
        if(this.requiredDocumentForUploads.length > 0) {
            this.requiredDocumentForUploads.forEach(file => {
                var name = file.attachment_type  // attachment_type is using for naming
                if(document.querySelector("[name=" + name + "]").files.length > 0) {
                    formData.append("requiredDocumentForUploadsNew[" + name + "]", document.querySelector("[name=" + name + "]").files[0])
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify at the frontend as below:

```
...
...
const entityData = new FormData();
entityData.append("Entities Open", JSON.stringify(login_entities));
axios
.post("/oneview/load_entity", entityData)
.then(response => {
   var entity_group = response.data.entity_group;
   var entity_code = response.data.entity_code;
   var entity_name = response.data.entity_name;
})
.catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
   alert(error);
});
```

Then use json.loads() at the backend as below:

```
...
...
login_entities = json.loads(request.POST.get('Entities Open'))
for i in login_entities:
   ...
   ...
```