# Not Getting List on Server Side using Angularjs mvc c#?

Tags: c#, angularjs

I'm using FormData to upload files. I also want to send an array of other data.

When I send just the image, it works fine. When I append some text to the formdata, it works fine. When I try to attach the 'ProIList' array below, everything else works fine but no array is sent

this is my angular.js file code :

```
this.AddPro = function (file, P) {
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);
formData.append("name", P.name);
formData.append("description", P.description);
formData.append("ProItems", P.ProIList);  // this is array list      

var Response = $http.post("/Product/AddProduct", formData,
{
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
})
.success(function (res) {
Response = res;
})
.error(function () {
 });
 return Response;
 }
```

this is my controller method :

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddProduct")]
public string AddProduct(Pro ProItems) // here i m not getting array 
{           
string Res = "";

            ProItems.name = name;
            ProItems.description = description;                       
            db.Promotions.Add(ProItems); // and here add product is done now want to add ProductItems table entry so how can do 
           db.SaveChanges();                  
 return Res;
}



this is my entity Pro :


 public class Pro 
 {

  public int id { get; set; }

   public int name {get; set;}

    public int descripation{ get; set; }

    public List<ProductItems> ProItems { get; set; }
     }
```

with my code i m getting all filed on api side like name,description,also image but just not getting list so can you please know any one where is my misteke.

Comment: try passing `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` or `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Comment: like this error is getting 'application is not defined'

Comment: @MansiParekh, OP also need to send image, will that content type work for it?

Comment: guys any one know on this stuff any solution then please let me know i need it to fix

Comment: @MansiParekh with your idea i m getting error on console so please any other wave?

Comment: @coderwill, have you debugged in controller, what you get for ProItems.ProItems?

Comment: yes i m getting ProItems.ProItems in array object but on server side not getting

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya i m write this code it's correct or wrong?or other code is missing do you know??

Comment: Looks ok, what is the implementation of your ProductItem on server and angular side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141619/discussion-between-coderwill-and-mukesh-modhvadiya).

Comment: You can use `JSON.stringify(P.ProIList)` to pass your array as string or you can check this link if it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104078/appending-array-to-formdata-and-send-via-ajax

Comment: sry @MansiParekh i am also try this wave but don't get result propare

Comment: any other solution guys???