# Laravel: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when sending values with multipart-form-data

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to access an array on a `multipart-form-data` request.

On my js code I add to the formData the object that I need this way:

```
for (const key in property) {
    if (typeof property[key] !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(key, property[key]);
        formData.append(`property[${key}]`, property[key]);
    }
}
```

The property has the array images and the value is an array like this:

[image]

Also in the same forData I send all the data from the images that I want to handle, and in this case the property contains an array of objects that are images previously stored in the database.
So, in my controller I have to following

```
 // Images that are already in database
 $propertyData = $request->input('property');
 $images = isset($propertyData['images'])? $propertyData['images'] : []
 foreach($images as $i) {
    $image = Image::find((int)$i['id']);
    if ( !is_null($image) ) {
        $image->update($i);
    }
}
```

But I got the error: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

I've tried to even convert each image on the javascript code to an array like the property, but i got the same error.

Comment: Does your `property` JS object have the key `images`? If yes, what's the value for that key?

Comment: Yes, it has the value for that key. I added and Image with the value that has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly append objects or arrays to `FormData`. You must add the keys and values one by one.

A way to do that is like so:

```
var formData = new FormData;
var arr = ['this', 'is', 'an', 'array'];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    formData.append('arr[]', arr[i]);
}
```

I use a helper function (note that this is in ES6 syntax) to do this:

```
export function appendFormdata(formData, data, previousKey) {
    if (data instanceof Object) {
        Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
            const value = data[key];
            if (previousKey) {
                key = `${previousKey}[${key}]`;
            }
            if (value instanceof Object && !Array.isArray(value) && !(value instanceof File)) {
                return appendFormdata(formData, value, key);
            }
            if (Array.isArray(value)) {
                value.forEach((val, i) => {
                    return appendFormdata(formData, val, `${key}[${i}]`);
                });
            } else {
                formData.append(key, value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For more details refer: [appending array to FormData and send via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16104078/7377984) and [Convert JS Object to form data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22783108/7377984)

Comment: Yeah, but this is an array inside another object. I’ve also tried that on each object inside my property object.

Comment: The only values you can directly append are strings. No arrays or objects or nested objects/arrays are allowed

Comment: Refer the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append). You can only append a `USVString` or `Blob` in FormData

Comment: Yeah but it’s working. I mean retrieving all the data from the property. I just need to find the correct way to iterate that property

Comment: Thanks, I solved it doing what you are saying, but keeping the data in a single object. `property.images.map((image, index) => { for (const key in image) { formData.append(`property[images][${index}][${key}]`, image[key]); }});`