# Axios, Proper way to make a post request for data including file, and Array object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, file-upload, axios

Recently, I was using Axios in my Frontend React project. Everything was going fine until I've to do post the following type of request in the server?

```
{
     "name": string,
     "image": <FILE>,
     "item_ids": [1, 2, 3],
}
```

forms.jsx

```
<Form onSubmit='<function_that_handles_posting>'>
    <Form.Group controlId="name">
        <Form.Control type="text" />
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group controlId="image">
        <Form.File />
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group controlId="list-input">
        // while posting the record, the data from here (comma separated data) is populated to an Array of
        <Form.Control type="text" />
    </Form.Group>
</Form>
```

I am using `new FormData()` to gather all the request information as below:

```
form_data = new FormData()
form_data.append('name', <value_for_name>)
form_data.append('image', <value_for_file>, <value_for_filename>)
form_data.append('item_ids', [1, 2, 3]) // value is in Array for sure

axios.post('<som_rest_url', form_data, {
           headers: {
                        'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data`
            }
         })
.then(response=> return response, err => return err)
```

The problem while doing post is, the data appended in `form_data`'s item_ids, the list will now become a string.

I went through the `FormData` definition, and found the following data structure it supports:

`append(name: string, value: string | Blob, fileName?: string): void;`

ie. I can not post my `content_ids` as a list in the request. I don't find any workaround to send the image uploads using Axios, this was my hope but when it comes to sending array of objects in a request's key it won't work.

Is there any solution that supports the above-mentioned request payload using Axios in a single request. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to convert it to JSON string, then parse it into your backend.**

```
var item_ids = JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]);
```

maybe some of the answers here can help you:
[appending array to FormData and send via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104078/appending-array-to-formdata-and-send-via-ajax)

Comment: I did the same thing, and I have to update simple logic in backend so that it can understand the coming data was actually a list. Thank you. Your help is appreciated.