# How to put array parameter into form data with Postman

Tags: postman, http-headers, httprequest, form-data

How can I pass this form data in postman?

[image]

I have tried this way and did not work:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16104139/6793637

you should check this post and https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/javascript/formdata-append-javascript-array-jsonstringify-how-to-cast-as-php-array?page=1

i think you should use JSON.parse(FOrmadata.field) in the server to convert the passed formData field to array