# Receive only empty arrays with object-tags in nodejs

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

If I send an array from frontend (Nuxt) to NodeJs, I receive only an empty array with object-tags. Whats the problem here?
I'm using express, body-parser, multer

**Array Example:**
`[ { "content": "<p>some content</p>", "asin": "asin-id" }, { "content": "<p>some content</p>", "asin": "asin-id" } ]`

**Console.log(req.body)**

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  postTitle: 'title',
  content: '[object Object],[object Object]'
}
```

```js
exports.createBlogPost = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    try {
        const post = new BlogPost({
            postTitle: req.body.postTitle,
            content: req.body.content,
            mainImage: req.file
        })
        await post.save()

        if(post) {
            return res.status(200).json({
                success: true,
                message: 'Saved blog post successfully',
                post: post
            })
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

**Nuxt.js**

```js
async savePost() {
      const data = new FormData()
      data.append('postTitle', this.postTitle)
      data.append('content', this.array)
      data.append('mainImage', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name)

      const blogPost = await this.$axios.$post('/api/create-blog-post', data)

      if (blogPost.success) {
        console.log(blogPost)
      }
    },
```

Comment: Do you mean that - "content: '[object Object],[object Object]'" is an empty array with object tags.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It‘s not really empty but it‘s unusable...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729276/how-can-i-get-the-full-object-in-node-jss-console-log-rather-than-object  I am expecting you are not fully familiar with console.log. check out the link

Comment: That‘s not the problem. It saves the „empty“ array in the db too

Comment: what do you get with calling    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))  before making axios call.

Comment: have you tried to "stringify" your array before sending it?

Comment: @satvikchoudhary then I get a completely emtpy array `{}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what we can do to send an array via `FormData`

Found this in the comments of [appending array to FormData and send via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104078/appending-array-to-formdata-and-send-via-ajax)

```js
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const ItemInArr = array[i]
  for (const prop in ItemInArr) {
    data.append(`content[${i}][${prop}]`, ItemInArr[prop])
  }
}
```

**Nuxt.js**

```js
async savePost() {
      const array = this.array
      const data = new FormData()
      data.append('postTitle', this.postTitle)
      data.append('mainImage', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name)

      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        const ItemInArr = array[i]
        for (const prop in ItemInArr) {
          data.append(`content[${i}][${prop}]`, ItemInArr[prop])
        }
      }
      const blogPost = await this.$axios.$post('/api/create-blog-post', data)

      if (blogPost.success) {
        console.log(blogPost)
      }
    },
```