# How to send javascript list from template to request.POST (django framework)

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have the javascript below that gets all checked box and it works well.

```
<script>
                function addlist() {
                    var array = []
                    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')

                    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                        array.push(checkboxes[i].value);
                    }
                }
</script>
```

I want to know how to submit the list ***array*** to views.py and get it via request.POST['']

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm trying to store this list somewhere where it can be called by request.POST[''] in views.py, but I don't know how to do that. In HTML there is a way to identify attributes with name="", but in javascript how can I make this call in views and use this list?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do [appending array to FormData and send via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104078/appending-array-to-formdata-and-send-via-ajax)? I don't understand why you're using `document.write` instead of sending a request to the server with `fetch` or similar. Before trying to POST an array, you might as well set up POSTing non-array data, then figure out the step to encode an array as form data. As it stands, none of the code shown has anything to do with Django or AJAX.

Comment: document.write was just to test. I removed it.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to identify the list array in the views.py function like i do with HTML elements. For example: my_list = request.POST['array']

Answer (score 2):

I solved the question in the follow way:

I created a hidden input to receive the list by javascript:

```
    <script>
        function addlist() {
            var array = []
            var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')

            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                array.push(checkboxes[i].value);
            }

            document.getElementById('precedent_list').value = array;
        }
    </script>


<input  type="hidden" style="outline-style: none;" id="precedent_list" name="precedent_list">
```

And I call the javascript function when the submit button is clicked:

```
    <p class="w3-center" style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 25px">
          <button class="w3-round-xxlarge general_button" type="submit" onclick="addlist()">Salvar</button>
   </p>
```

In views.py I receive the list in the follow way:

```
my_list = ''
my_list_= []
if 'precedent_list' in request.POST:
    my_list = request.POST['precedent_list']
my_list = my_list.replace(',',' ')
for j in my_list.split():
    my_list_.append(int(j))
```

Comment: just do request.POST.getlist("precedent_list[]") will return list by default