# how to append array of objects to formData

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have a dynamic form and i save all values in one `useState` that name is `formFields`and output like this:

```
   {
      title: "aaa",
      description: "bbb",
      second_description: "ccc",
      step_number: 1,
      image: null,
    },
   {
      title: "zzz",
      description: "xxx",
      second_description: "eee",
      step_number: 2,
      image: null,
    }
]
```

i sholud save this array of objects and send as POST request like this:

```
{
 steps: [
         {
      title: "aaa",
      description: "bbb",
      second_description: "ccc",
      step_number: 1,
      image: null,
    },
   {
      title: "zzz",
      description: "xxx",
      second_description: "eee",
      step_number: 2,
      image: null,
    }

    ]
}
```

but with this code i can't append this objects inside steps[]

```
   formFields.forEach((item) => {
      formData.append("steps[]", item);
    });
```

and show me in console like this:
`steps: Array [ "[object Object]", "[object Object]" ]`

objects save like `string` in `steps`! , but i want to save object
how i can do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I append an array to 'formdata' in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026539/can-i-append-an-array-to-formdata-in-javascript)

Comment: @Konrad with `JSON.stringify`   | save like this : ```"{\"title\":\"aaaaaaaaaa\",\"description\":\"aaaaaaaaa\",\"second_description\":\"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\",\"step_number\":1,\"image\":null}"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the below code, it is not saved in the way you want

```
formFields.forEach((item) => {
      formData.append("steps[]", item);
});
```

because `steps` is an array, you need to assign the number of each array to it:

```
       const name = "steps";

        formFields.forEach((item,i) => {
            formData.append((name + '[' + i + ']'+["[title]"]), item["title"]);
            formData.append((name + '[' + i + ']'+["[description]"]), item["description"]);
            formData.append((name + '[' + i + ']'+["[second_description]"]), item["second_description"]);
            formData.append((name + '[' + i + ']'+["[step_number]"]), item["step_number"]);
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

does this answer your question?

```
let formFields = [{
      title: "aaa",
      description: "bbb",
      second_description: "ccc",
      step_number: 1,
      image: null,
    },
   {
      title: "zzz",
      description: "xxx",
      second_description: "eee",
      step_number: 2,
      image: null,
    }]
;

let formData = {};
formData.steps = [];

formFields.forEach((item) => {
    formData.steps.push(item);
});

JSON.stringify(formData);

//output 

'{"steps":[{"title":"aaa","description":"bbb","second_description":"ccc","step_number":1,"image":null},{"title":"zzz","description":"xxx","second_description":"eee","step_number":2,"image":null}]}'
```

Comment: steps not append to `formData` when i send as POST API