# How to append array data to FormData when the type of one of the properties is in the file format

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, multipartform-data, form-data

I am using formdata for file upload operations...

How do I load the data in array format (one of the properties type is file).

**JSON.stringify** didn't work

How I use it on the controller side

```
public class SampleData
{
    public string t { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase u { get; set; }
    public SampleData() { }
}
public JsonResult Save(FormCollection model, SampleData[] upls) {
  ...
}
```

sample data

```
var data = [{t:"lorem",u: file}, {t:"ipsum",u: file}, { t:"generator", u: file}];
```

I tried to formdata append in 3 different structures below, but i didn't succeed

My source for the [third example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25387599/8257277)

```
$.each(data, function(index,vs) {
   formdata.append('upls[]', vs); // Sample 1
})

$.each(data, function(index,vs) {
   formdata.append('upls[][t]', vs.t); // Sample 2
   formdata.append('upls[][u]', vs.u);
});

$.each(data, function(index,vs) {
   var f = new Array(); // Sample 3
   f.t = vs.t;
   f.u = vs.u;
   formdata.append('upls[]', f);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using loop directly to append data try to use Object loop as below:-

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(entry => {
      const [key, value] = entry;
      formData.append(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  })
```

Here is how you can check it by looping formdata:-

```
  for(let [key, value] of formData) {
    alert(`${key} = ${value}`); // key1 = value1, then key2 = value2
  }
```

Full code:-

```
  let formData = new FormData();
  Object.entries(data).forEach(entry => {
      const [key, value] = entry;
      formData.append(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  })
  for(let [key, value] of formData) {
    alert(`${key} = ${value}`); // key1 = value1, then key2 = value2
  }
```

Comment: There is no solution other than the **JSON.stringify** ?